# A function "alias" that needs to pass along parameters

Tags: powershell, args

I have put the following into my `$PROFILE`:

```
function dir
{
    Get-ChildItem -Force $args
}
```

What I want is a simple "dir" command that lists *all* files, including hidden and system files.

However, as soon as I pass some parameters along:

```
dir \ -Directory
```

I am rewarded with a full listing of my root followed by this error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\myuser-Directory' because
>   it does not exist.

My intention was of course that my little homebrewed "alias" would expand into this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force \ -Directory
```

But instead "-Directory" gets treated as a string literal. How can I make my dir function pass arguments the way I intended (rather than as an array of string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$args` is an array. If you use it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force $args
```

it's the same as if you did this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Path '\', '-Directory'
```

which works (in a way), because the parameter `-Path` accepts array input.

Use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to avoid this pitfall:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force @args
```